Filtering or slicing based on calendar table removes all data
I'm using two data tables to create visuals on a report, where both tables have a datetime column. I want to filter or slice every visual on the report based on a datetime range.
I've created a calendar table, and added relationships between the calendar and my other tables. My calendar table was created using the following formula:
Calendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2022, 01, 01), TODAY())


The above calendar has a Date column, formatted as a date hierarchy, which I'm trying to use to create filters and slicers. My problem is, when I apply any date filter or slicer to the page, no matter the range, all data is removed.
How can I apply a date filter to multiple visuals at once? What am I doing wrong here?

This happens because of data type incompatibility between relationship columns. As an example, Calendar table has data column and fact table has date time column, and we are making a relationship between those two columns filter won't work.
Make both data types same for date, pick date time or date for both columns.
